# Powerpoint 2007 break links on the datasheet of an embedded chart object

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I would like to break the links in the datasheet of an embedded chart object .
This code updates the links, but I need the links broken.
Thanks

```
pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
```

PS. How do you update multiple link sources without and error message.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved this once by simply assigning a `vbnullstring` or `""` as link, which then appears in the link dialog as `NULL`  (so I am taking about charts pasted from Excel it this is what you mean by embedded chart; because your question makes no sense if you mean a 'native' ppt2007+ chart object)

Comment: Actually, I am talking about a chart created in Powerpoint, not excel.

Answer (score 0):

Ungroup the shape that represents the chart.  That breaks the link, converts the chart into a vector (ie, EMF/WMF) graphic.